# CORS issue when redirect to Google OAuth endpoint

Tags: reactjs, .net, cors, google-oauth, client-server

We are trying to do Google Auth using React as a client and .NET as backend (identity without UI).

First, we try to access "**external-login**" endpoint on backend from frontend. But then CORS issue arise.

```
        [Route("external-login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var command = new GenerateExternalAuthPropertiesCommand(provider, returnUrl);

            var properties = await _mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
            return Challenge(properties, provider);
        }
```

So frontend(**domain1.com**) calls backend(**domain2.com**), the backend does redirection to Google OAuth endpoint. Actually, it tries to do OPTIONS request to google endpoint and for sure it failed.
[image]

Then we decided to make the same origin(scheme, domain and port) through the Nginx. So let's say we have a server, there is **domain.com** which points to Nginx.

We set

`domain.com/auth/front` as a reverse_proxy pass for frontend container

`domain.com/auth/back` as a reverse_proxy pass for backend container.

it works: we can access the backend endpoint via `domain.com/auth/back/test`
and frontend endpoints via `domain.com/auth/front/test`.

Now OPTIONS request disappeared, but still, we face CORS issue when we access Google endpoint.

[image]
[image]

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: *the backend does redirection to Google OAuth endpoint* That sounds wrong. You want to generate an oauth-url on your backend, then just give the url to the client. Now let the client open the url in the existing window, or a new one.

Comment: it's not possible in context of using Identity. It is building everything on its own and doing the redirection.

Comment: @super, sorry but I didn't ask how to do it correctly. For doing correctly - I can use different approaches(from identity UI, building URI as you've suggested, to implementing custom auth server with is4 or openiddict). BUT, I'm asking what is the problem and why it throws cors even if the origin is the same.

Comment: accounts.google.com is not the same origin. That's the reason you're getting CORS errors. The fact that you redirect a request there from your backend makes no difference.

Comment: @super, the situation will be the same if I open link from frontend, accounts.google.com is not the same origin. And currently my back and front are the same origin.

Comment: No. If you open the link in your browser accounts.google.com IS the origin. Your client can either navigate the current window there, or open the link in a new tab/window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246566/discussion-between-andriy-and-super).

Comment: Google will then redirect the broser back to your redirect URL once the permission has been given. This is the normal flow of things.

Comment: @super yeah I know the flow of OAuth, but the question is why we get cors if it is the same server which initiates request to accounts.google.com? What it the difference? either from frontend or from backend - they are both in the same scheme/domain/port(domain.com), so the origin is the same.

Comment: What do you mean **initiates request**? No matter how you try to access the google URL, if you do it from the browser (or any client that respects CORS) from a different origin you will get a CORS error. I'm not sure what part you are confused about here. If you still havn't managed to explain what the question is you really need to clarify your question.

Comment: @super I mean got redirection and follow that redirection. Get redirection (get req to back (domain.com/auth/back from domain.com/auth/front) and follow redirection (go to accounts.google.com from domain.com/auth/back).
You have suggested to follow from frontend (domain.com/auth/front). But why it should work, the origin in both cases is domain.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the problem was simple. After discussing it with colleagues it turned out that the XHR request cannot do that. To make this work - we need to change the XHR call to a simple  tag.
Why it didn't work? - Because of security, XHR requests shouldn't be allowed to do such requests with redirects so CORS blocked it. With the form, it will redirect the user which gives visibility and the Antiforgery token gives security from a malicious js execution standpoint.